# Embedded Ruby form - validating email with specific domain

Tags: regex, ruby

I am creating an embedded Ruby form and I would like the validation to allow 9 characters before the beginning, but specifcially starting with an 'x', so x12345678@a2z.ie would be a valid email while 12345678@a2z.ie would not be valid.

a2z.ie is the domain and is required.

I have the REGEX code: `x+\d{8}+@a2z.ie`

The code I have is this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", :class => 'form-control', :validation => 'x+\d{8}+@a2z.ie' %>
  </div>
```

I know this code is wrong because it still allows any user's email.

Comment: Try `:validation => /\Ax\d{8}@a2z\.ie\z/`

Comment: If `:validation` does not work, try replacing it with `:pattern`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  `:validation => /\Ax\d{8}@a2z\.ie\z/` did not work.
`:validation => '/\Ax\d{8}@a2z\.ie\z/'` did not work.
`:pattern => /\Ax\d{8}@a2z\.ie\z/` did not work.
`:pattern => '/\Ax\d{8}@a2z\.ie\z/'` did not work. :(

Comment: Do not put the regex inside single quotes, it will never work. So, the problem is not just with regex, you need to fix your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried both with and without, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Used an email validator Ruby file instead.

Using Devise as well, if that helps.

In user.rb, add:

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
```

Create a `validators` folder in models. Then create email_validator.rb in said folder and add this to it:

(app/models/validators/email_validator.rb) :

```
require 'mail'
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
        begin
            m = Mail::Address.new(value)
            # We must check that value contains a domain, the domain has at least
            # one '.' and that value is an email address  
            r = m.domain.present? && m.domain.match('\.') && m.address == value
            s = m.domain.present? && m.domain.match('\@a2z.ie') && m.address == value

            # Update 2015-Mar-24
            # the :tree method was private and is no longer available.
            # t = m.__send__(:tree)
            # We need to dig into treetop
            # A valid domain must have dot_atom_text elements size > 1
            # user@localhost is excluded
            # treetop must respond to domain
            # We exclude valid email values like <user@localhost.com>
            # Hence we use m.__send__(tree).domain
            # r &&= (t.domain.dot_atom_text.elements.size > 1)
        rescue
            r = false
        end
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid. Please enter xEMPLOYEENUMBER@a2z.ie, e.g. x12345678@a2z.ie") unless (r && s)
    end
end
```

Wasn't exactly what I wanted, but is somewhat.

Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise